# Vaadin item click listener double click behaviour

Tags: client-server, vaadin, onitemclicklistener, double-click, vaadin8

I am working on a vaadin application. I have provided left single click and left double click actions on a grid row via item click listner. In case of left single click it works correctly, but problem is that whenever i do left double click on grid, the listner gets invoked 3 times i.e.

- Single Click
- Single Click, then
- Double Click 
  On first invoke, selected item is correct but on second and third invoke the selected item is null. Moreover sometimes there is delay in sending the click action to server(i am not getting it why). On my machine it is working correctly because client and server are both on same machine, but on actual system it looks like the request from client(browser) either reach late to server or does not reach at all. 
  Can anyone help me in this?
  Note- Grid selection model is SingleSelection.

  ```
   @Override
   public void itemClick(final ItemClick<PersonData> itemClickEvent) {
       final PersonData data = itemClickEvent.getItem();
       if (itemClickEvent.getMouseEventDetails().isDoubleClick()) {
            //some logic
           } else {
            //some logic
       }
   }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

First, there's a potential bug or a limitation: the way click events work in browsers is that when you double click an element, it actually fires three events:

1. a single click event after the first click
2. a second single click event after the second click
3. a double click event (assuming the second click happened fast enough after the first one)

You can test this out in a plain HTML document like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button ondblclick="d()" onclick="s()">Double-click here</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function d() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "Double";
}
function s() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "Single";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You'll note that if you double-click the button, it'll print "SingleSingleDouble". So the framework's server-side events reflect the browser events in a naive way.

It would be difficult to create a server-side fix that would make the server-side events behave in a more intuitive way due to the way client-server RPC calls work in Vaadin. Here's a simplified breakdown:
If there's a server-side listener for a particular event like "click":

- If there is no ongoing request, an RPC is sent to the server immediately when the event is caught in the browser. So when the first click of the double-click occurs -> boom, sent to the server
- If there *is* an ongoing request, any client-side events that should be sent to the server are placed in a queue and the queue's events are sent to the server once the previous response has arrived

As you've noticed, the network latency may come into play here - if the request-response cycle is very fast, you might even end up making three separate requests to the server; on a slow network, it might take a noticeable delay after the first server-side listener activation before the second one does.

So: while it would seemingly make sense to deduce on the server that in the case of "single-single-double" triplet the "logical" event would be just one double-click event, what the server usually receives first is just the one single-click event, while the second click event and the double click event are possibly waiting in a queue in the browser. The server has no way of knowing that it was actually a double-click. If there's a fix to be made, it needs to be done on the client-side of the Grid implementation; I'd recommend creating a GitHub ticket about it.

Next up, as you have Grid where rows can be selected, the first click on the item selects it, the second click deselects it. Here, I'd recommend using a multi-selection grid, as there the selection is not connected to clicking a row but happens via checking a checkbox. That way, you can still have a click listener on the row and a selection that doesn't get deselected accidentally. You'll just need to make sure the previous selection is cleared when a new row is selected; this can be done in a selection listener.